# Use timestamp with mat-datepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material DatePicker

I receive a timestamp from the API and must send back a timestamp to it, however mat-datepicker use date formats such as ISO 8601 string.

My current work around is to manually convert the data back and forth, when receiving data from the API and before sending it back.

```
// convert date from timestamp to ISO in order to work with datepicker
   myDate = myDate ? new Date(myDate) : null;

// convert date back to timestamp
   myDate = myDate !== null ? Date.parse(myDate) : null;
```

I don't find this solution very elegant or efficient. Is there a way to directly use timestamps with angular material datePicker? Perhaps using a dateAdapter?

Comment: Please add the code so we can help you.

Comment: @Spritzig I've added some code

Comment: You want to convert you date to timestamps ?

Comment: No, this is what I already do manually because material datepicker doesn't work with timestamp. What I'd like to do is to make datepicker to work with timestamp in order to avoid manually converting the data

Comment: Can you please take a look here maybe it will help.
https://logbon72.github.io/angular-material-datetimepicker/